# Alternative alarm clocks

Tags: iphone, ios, sound-volume, alarm, clock

I have iPhone 6 and iOS 10. I notice that if the mute button is on or the volume is at zero then the alarm doesn't go off.  I see many others note the same thing.

Is there an non-native app I could use to get around this issue until some new update resolves it? I keep forgetting to check my volume and mute settings before bed and am getting into professional trouble. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  All non-system apps are forced to obey the volume setting and/or the mute switch.  Only Apple's Clock app can produce audible alarms in these cases.